# Is there a way to convert "QRST-code" to longitude/latitude?

Tags: google-maps

I did a lot of research for that topic - but it seems not enough, so I'm here asking for help :-)
Google Maps could use QRST-code for specifing a location. I've got a line like that:

```
trtqtqsss...
```

and so on. In some other forums I've found out that GM once used that in an URL-Syntax. But now it seems it doesn't work anymore - or at least I don't know how.

Here is an example of the link that won't work anymore:

```
kh0.google.com/kh?n=404&v=8&t=tq
kh1.google.com/kh?n=404&v=8&t=tr
```

In this URL, the quadrants are specified with the string after `t=`.

Is there a converter or something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the information at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14793/How-Google-Map-Works help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

From what I gather, the long string of `trtqtqss` indicates, in essence, a binary search for the location.  It roughly translates like this:

1. Start with the letter `t`. This gives you "the sholw world"
2. Look for your point on the map. If it's in the top left quadrant, add a `q`. If top right, add `r`. Bottom right, add `s`. Bottom left, add `t`.
3. Zoom in on the new quadrant. Repeat.

Every time you add a letter you halve the size of the tile, and find a new bottom left corner. If we think of the world map as a rectangle of width and height = 1, we can find a new corner for each character added. This is the essence of the algorithm you linked in your comment.

With that, plus the "Rosetta stone" (again from your link) of a known string-to-satellite image translation, I give you the following code. This will give you the Longitude/Latitude of a point based on your string. Compile it, then pass the string as argument to the executable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

double NormalToMercator(double y) {
  double pi;
  pi = 2 * asin(1);
  y -= 0.5;
  y *= 2 * pi; 
  y = exp( 2 * y );
  y = ( y - 1 ) / ( y + 1 );
  y = -asin( y );
  return -y * 180 / pi;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  double x=0, y=0, scale=1;
  char buf[100]={' '};
  int ii;

  buf[0]=argv[1][0];
  for(ii = 1; ii < strlen(argv[1]); ii++) {
    buf[ii-1]=argv[1][ii];
    scale *= 0.5;
    switch (tolower(argv[1][ii])) {
      case 'q':
        y+=scale;
        break;
      case 'r':
        y+=scale;
        x+=scale;
        break;
      case 's':
        x+=scale;
        break;
      case 't':
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    printf("the string %s gets you to (x,y): %.9lf, %.9lf\n", \
      buf, x, y);
    }
  printf("the final lat/long is %.5lf, %.5lf\n", 360.0 * (x - 0.5), NormalToMercator(y));
}
```

The intermediate `printf` statement is there to show you how the algorithm is slowly making its way to the right location. I tested this with the string from the link in your comment (`tsrrtrsqsqqqrqrtsst`), and got the coordinates `153.39935ºE 28.32372ºS` (note - a negative number for longitude means "W", and a negative number for latitude means "S". I got 153.39935, -28.32372). When I entered those in Google maps, I got the picture of the hospital that you get when entering the [link from blog post](http://khm.google.com/kh?v=88&t=tsrrtrsqsqqqrqrtsst).

Comment: Thank you! I've tested it but unfortunalety the result isn't that right. I'm wondering that every case has the same formula. Might there be a different formular for every case? I've found something like that at another forum (pseudo code I guess and it's about converting to XY coordinates):
case '0':
break;
case '1':
tileX |= mask;
break;
case '2':
tileY |= mask;
break;
case '3':
tileX |= mask;
tileY |= mask;
break;
(sorry, don't know how to format it properly for a better reading)

Comment: Do you have a "known string with known location"? It would help greatly with debugging if you did...

Comment: Maybe this link helps: http://intepid.com/posts/484
(Thank you so much for working on that!)

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Now it works great and the result was good. :-) THX!!